# How to dynamically change font family based on different languages using react-native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I am developing a mobile app using react-native. The app needs to handle multiple languages (English and Sinhala). Some mobile phones support Sinhala fonts and display them correctly. But some of not support the Sinhala language. For that, I want to load the font using the font folder within the app.

I add font folder to the app and linking them using the react-native link. But font not loading correctly.

1. I want to know how to load custom fonts to react-native
2. How to load font family dynamically, when user change language

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, were you able to figure out a solution?

Comment: abhishekgupta Still not

Answer (score 2):

I might be a little late but I found this solution that you can use to dynamically change the font based on the language.

**1.**

```
import NativeModules from 'react-native'
```

**2.**

Then use this inline if to change the language when the user changes the device locale.

```
fontFamily: ((NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier == 'az_AZ') ? 'Alice' : 'DesirasNonCommercial')
```

If you have more than two languages, you can create a module and implement a function to check the locale and return the corresponding font. Then you can simply use the returned value in the fontFamily.
Also If you have a button to manually change the language, you can modify the function above and add an event listener to return the appropriate fontFamily when the language changing button is triggered.